# Cmd+3, Cmd+4 not working!

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control

I've been using <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>~<kbd>4</kbd> shortcuts for switching spaces on older versions of OS X.

But after upgrading to Lion (10.7.4), <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> do not work!

I need them to switch tabs in web browser and they are very useful shortcuts in Xcode too.

I looked in Keyboard in System Preference but couldn't find where they are defined.

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> work in both Chrome and Xcode. (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>~<kbd>6</kbd> works also)

I don't know why <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> do not work in any application!

My guess is they're defined for something else globally. But I can't find where.

Another guess is they're probably defined for 'Switch to Desktop 3, 4' since I've been using old version of OSX and upgraded to Lion.

Like DMan pointed out, after removing 'Switch to Desktop 1, 2', <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> work just fine.

But where's 'Switch to Desktop 3 and 4'??

Comment: I don't have Lion but you can switch tab with ctrl + tab.

Comment: Switching tabs in what? A browser? Safari has never supported command 1~0. Chrome and Xcode do work as you've indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open System Preferences -> Keyboard
2. Click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab.
3. From the left column, choose Mission Control.
4. In the Pane on the right, you should be able to re-set the keyboard shortcuts for your spaces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see Cmd+1, Cmd+2 are defined for 'Switch to Desktop 1, 2'. I disabled them. But where's 'Switch to Desktop 3 and 4'??

Comment: I believe the options for 'Switch to Desktop N' appear once you have N spaces added via Mission Control.

Comment: GOD! You're my saviour, noffle!! Thank you so much!! Everything works just fine!!